# Notes about the ring of $p$-adic integers $\Bbb Z_p$

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, profinite-groups

I'm studing profinte groups. I'm using Wilson's book "Profinite Groups". Here the ring of $p$-adic integers $\Bbb Z_p$ is introduced as inverse limit of rings $\Bbb Z/p^n\Bbb Z$.

I'm searching for some lecture notes (available on the web if possibile) that explain the following things (I can't find them in the Wilson's book):

- $\Bbb Z_p$ is a PID (and other informations about its ideals)
- $\Bbb Z_p\simeq\operatorname{End}(C_{p^{\infty}})$ where $C_{p^{\infty}}$ is the $p$-Prufer group.
- This last one is the most important: the torsion part of the group of unit in $\Bbb Z_p$ is cyclic: $T((\Bbb Z_p)^{\times})\simeq C_{p-1}$.

Any suggested reading will be appreciated. Many thanks to all.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is actually a discrete valuation ring whose residue field is $\mathbb{F}_p$, the finite field on $p$ elements.

Comment: I think answer to your first and third question could be found in third section of second chapter of serre's book "A course in arithmetic".

Comment: Many many thanks